# finding $f$ function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For which of the sets $\mathbb{X}:= \mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$, there exist a function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{X})\rightarrow\mathbb{X}$ that for all $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{X})\setminus \lbrace\phi\rbrace$, $f(A)\in A?$ I want to find $f$ function? please help me.

Comment: For all of them. This is obvious in the first three cases. In the last two, it requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: In my text this question is before the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: And why would that matter? It does not mean anything whether it is in the same section, or after, or before, or in another book, or if you thought of it on your own. The answer does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f:\mathcal{P}(A)-\{\varnothing\} \to A$ satisfying the condition $f(A)\in A$ is called a *choice function on $A$*. 
In the case of $\Bbb{N}$, $\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Q}$, you can construct the choice function explicitly. For example, you can define $f:\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\to\Bbb{N}$ as like:
$$
f(A):=\min A 
$$
In the case of $\Bbb{Z}$ you can construct the bijection $g:\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{N}$. If we define $h(A)=g^{-1}(f(g_*(A)))$ (where $g_*(A)$ is image of $A$ under $g$) then $h$ satisfies $f(A)\in A$ for all nonempty $A$. Similarly, you can construct the bijection between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{N}$ and you can also define the function satisfy the given condition.

In the case $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$, you can prove the existence of these functions. However, there is no explicit construction for the function satisfy the given condition. In fact, the existence of these function requires the axiom of choice and it is necessary to prove the existence of choice function on $\Bbb{R}$. It is known that '$\Bbb{R}$ has no choice function' consistent with ZF.

Comment: The last line should probably be "$\mathcal P(\Bbb R)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ has no choice function".